# How to edit an element from an array in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have been working on a to do list app in flutter and now I am trying to implement an edit function in which the user can select the element the user wants to edit and finally saving those changes made. For doing this, I created a function that calls the array which stores the uploaded items to then target the selected element from the array and finally give it a new value which would be the edited text. I have used this process before in react native but since flutter uses dart I have been getting some problems like I can’t just add indexOf(index) because an integer can’t be used in ToDoElement which is a string, also I don’t know how can I assign a new value to that selected element since this is my second week learning flutter. How can I achieve this edit function? Please correct me if my idea of doing this is wrong.

EDIT: I have recieved help and now I am getting an error on _editDialog when calling the _editToDoItem function, on index because `Undefined name 'index'`.

code related to the edit function

```
class ToDoElement {
  String task;
  final DateTime timeOfCreation;

  ToDoElement(this.task, this.timeOfCreation);
}

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  createState() => MyAppState();
}



class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  List<ToDoElement> _toDoItems = [];
  TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();

  void _addToDoItem(String task) {
    if(task.isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() {  
        _toDoItems.add(ToDoElement(task, DateTime.now()));
      });
    }
  }

  void _editToDoItem(String newText, int index) {
    setState(() {
      _toDoItems[index].task = newText;
    });
  }

  void _removeTodoItem(int index) {
    setState(() => _toDoItems.removeAt(index));
  }

  _editDialog(BuildContext context) {
    return showDialog(context: context, builder: (context) {
      return Dialog(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
          ),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          height: 180,
          width: 100,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
                Container(
                  height: 60, 
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: _controller,
                    autofocus: true,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18,),
                  )
                ), 
                Container(
                  height: 65,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5,),
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    color: Colors.red,
                    child: Text('EDIT', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
                    
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      _editToDoItem(_controller.text, index); // error on index, Undefined name 'index'
                      FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
                    },
                  ),
                ),                                          
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
  }
```

full main.dart

```
class ToDoElement {
  String task;
  final DateTime timeOfCreation;

  ToDoElement(this.task, this.timeOfCreation);
}

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  createState() => MyAppState();
}



class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  List<ToDoElement> _toDoItems = [];
  TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();

  void _addToDoItem(String task) {
    if(task.isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() {  
        _toDoItems.add(ToDoElement(task, DateTime.now()));
      });
    }
  }

  void _editToDoItem(String newText, int index) {
    setState(() {
      _toDoItems[index].task = newText;
    });
  }

  void _removeTodoItem(int index) {
    setState(() => _toDoItems.removeAt(index));
  }

  _editDialog(BuildContext context) {
    return showDialog(context: context, builder: (context) {
      return Dialog(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
          ),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          height: 180,
          width: 100,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
                Container(
                  height: 60, 
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: _controller,
                    autofocus: true,
                    /*onSubmitted: (val) {
                      _addToDoItem(val);
                      _controller.clear();
                    },*/
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18,),
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: 'Add a task here...',
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 2),
                      ),
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 2),
                      ),
                      
                    ),
                  )
                ),

              
                   
                Container(
                  height: 65,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5,),
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    color: Colors.red,
                    child: Text('EDIT', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
                    
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      _editToDoItem(_controller.text, index);
                      FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
                    },
                  ),
                ),                                          
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
  }

  Widget _buildToDoItem(String toDoText, int index) {
    return SizedBox(
      child: Container(
        height: 58,
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 22.0, right: 22.0, bottom: 12,),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(width: 1.5, color: Colors.red),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(18)),
        ),
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children:[
            Expanded(
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(
                  toDoText,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                ),
                onTap: () => null,
              ),
            ),
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('Edit', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 16.5),),
              onPressed: () => _editDialog(context),
            ),
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('Delete', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 16.5),),
              onPressed: () => _removeTodoItem(index),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  int compareElement(ToDoElement a, ToDoElement b) =>
      a.timeOfCreation.isAfter(b.timeOfCreation) ? -1 : 1;

  Widget _buildToDoList() {
    _toDoItems.sort(compareElement);
    return Expanded(
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _toDoItems.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          if (index < _toDoItems.length) {
            return _buildToDoItem(_toDoItems[index].task, index);
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(50),
          child: AppBar(
            centerTitle: true,
            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
            title: Text('To Do List', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,),),
          )
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
          },
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 60,
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(22),
                child: Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 10,
                      child: Container(
                        height: double.infinity,
                        child: TextField(
                          controller: _controller,
                          autofocus: true,
                          onSubmitted: (val) {
                            _addToDoItem(val);
                            _controller.clear();
                          },
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18,),
                          
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            hintText: 'Add a task here...',
                            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 2),
                            ),
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 2),
                            ),
                            
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 4,    
                      child: Container(
                        height: double.infinity,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12),
                        child: RaisedButton(
                          textColor: Colors.white,
                          color: Colors.red,
                          child: Text('ADD', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
                          
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            _addToDoItem(_controller.text);
                            _controller.clear();
                            FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
                          },
                        ),
                      ),                                          
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ), 
              _buildToDoList()
            ]
          ), 
                 
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

if you have any questions please let me know in the comments;)

Comment: Probably best adding the details about the error in your question, rather than just your code comments

Comment: @David I just updated my question I hope it is clearer. I see you uploaded an answer, Give me some time before checking it in my code because my sister is using the computer right now:)

Answer (score 3):

The reason you're getting an error is because your use of `.indexOf` is wrong. It should be used to discover the index of a known element, whereas you already know the index and instead want to change the element. Instead, you can directly access an element using the `[]` operator: `someList[index] = someNewValue`.

However, you also have an error before this. The line `final items = [..._toDoItems];` is unnecessary in this case and would cause serious problems in other cases (for instance if your list of data were a list of `int` or `String`, as these are constants). All this line does is copy (unpack) all elements from `_toDoItems` into a new list. Instead you can just directly edit your original list.

Finally, your `ToDoElement` property `task` is `final`, but you want to modify `task`. However, you can't change final variables. Your options are either to replace the element in `_toDoItems` with a new `ToDoElement` (from scratch), or you change this to a non final variable. I suggest the latter.

Anyway, to fix the problem (using the latter method), you can simply change your `_editToDoItem` method to the following:

```
void _editToDoItem(int index, String newText) {
    _toDoItems[index].task = newText;
    setState(() {});
}
```

And remove the `final` from your `ToDoElement`:

```
class ToDoElement {
  String task;
  final DateTime timeOfCreation;

  ToDoElement(this.task, this.timeOfCreation);
}
```

Comment: So In your code, the _editToDoItem function calls the original array to then target the selected element using [index].task and that is equal to the new text right? If so then what is setState for?

Comment: Flutter is declarative, which means you declare that, for instance, the text of your Text widget in your todo list is equal to the `task` value in an element in your _toDoItems list, which is your data. In an ideal world, the moment you change a value in your _toDoItems, your widget should change, however, to optimise your app and to avoid the UI constantly rebuilding, using battery unnecessarily when no data changes, Flutter defines that you must call `setState` to trigger a refresh (rebuild). You can read more here: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt

Comment: Hey David! I added an edit button that passes the _editToDoItem function like this, `onPressed: () => _editToDoItem(index, newText)` and I am getting these errors `Undefined name 'index'` and `Undefined name 'newText'`, Why am I getting those errors?

Comment: Also this is the _editToDoItem function `void _editToDoItem(int index, String newText) {
    setState(() {
      _toDoItems[index].task = newText;
    });
  }`

Comment: That's no longer really a Flutter problem, more just a general programming error. `index` and `newText` are just the random names given to those arguments in the scope of the `_editToDoItem`  method. You have to pass valid variables to this function, similar to what you did with your create button, where you passed `_controller.text`.

Comment: yes, I already tried _controller.text and it seems to be fine but I need to pass 2 parameters so I need one more and I have no Idea what should go there, I think I should add a key instead of task so that I dont have to use index in the edit function and that way now I would have to pass just one parameter I think, would that work?

Comment: Yes, you need to give it an index. If you're creating this button in your `_buildToDoItem` you already have an `index` variable you can use, otherwise you have to find it some other way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219761/discussion-between-david-and-juan-martin-zabala).